# Google Sheet custom function not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

So I've got this simple thing I'm trying to do.  It's a journal tool.  The way it works is you fill in the "form" then you click a save button.  The first time the I click the save button, everything works as you would expect it to work.  The second time I click the save button, it doesn't save anything.  The third time I click the save button, it saves what it should have saved when I clicked the button the second time.

Here is a link to my google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11KTJpU8L9ZMrQ4EPQEJ5x3nHt1bl_6hzkEaYD-uq5HM

Here is my code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var copyFormat = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT;
var copyText = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;

function save_entry() {
  
  let namedranges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
  let daytemplate = namedranges[0];
  let today = namedranges[1];

  let numRows = daytemplate.getRange().getNumRows();

  sheet.insertRows(30,numRows+2);
  let celltext = "A" + (32);
  sheet.setCurrentCell(sheet.getRange(celltext));
  
  let target = sheet.getCurrentCell();

  today.getRange().copyTo(target,copyFormat,false);
  today.getRange().copyTo(target,copyText,false);

  daytemplate.getRange().copyTo(today.getRange());

}
```

This should all be very simple.  "today" is a named ranged that contains a copy of "daytemplate".  It basically functions as a form.  When I click save, a copy of "today" is entered at row 32 (after creating space for it), and then "daytemplate" is copied over "today".

I don't understand why it behaves weird.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Please set the sheet to vllow view access

Comment: Done sorry.  Set to view.

Comment: Hi there @user1672528! Could you please write an answer detailing the approach to fix the issue?

Comment: To fix my problem, I got my named ranges explicitly and by name instead of trying to get them from the array of named ranges. getnamedrange("daytemplate"), eg.